# What kind of memory it is?

Tags: memory

I was reading about various memory techniques : mnemonics, memory space, peg system, space repetition etc . They are used when I have to memorize something by myself for longer duration.

There are many other memories which are in my mind but I dint memorize them by myself. They are automatically stored. Like : my travel experience, some childhood activity etc . Some of them are faded some are still very clear. I can visualize them clearly.

But there are some memories, I cant visualize them. But I still remember. For example : if I try to visualize or write position of 'G' key on laptop keyboard, I can't. But still when I type, my fingers know its exact position. Similarly, if someone asks me to write my national anthem, I can't. But I can sing it without any mistake. Why does it happen so. Can't I remember everything in this way instead of any other memory technique? The advantage of this is quick recall.

Comment: Umm I think I got it why I cant visualize them because I dint involved my eyes(one of the sense) to remember them. So I even can type with my closed eyes too.

Comment: Interesting question! I once wondered the same thing, I guess memory retrieval has to do with memory encoding. E.g., encode the keyboard outline via typing, thus retrieve it via typing as well. Hope to see scientific explanation.

Comment: Another good point: when I try to recall PIN code of my permanent residential, I visualize the image of near by post office. But in reality that post office has different PIN. Moreover, I hardly use this PIN, 5-6 times in an year. I never used any sense to remember this still I can recall it easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The travel experience etc, are [episodic memories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episodic_memory). The duration of these memories mostly depend on emotion and novelty.

The typing and singing, are [procedural memories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_memory). They are formed with practice. Repetition and consistency are the two most important factors for this type of memory. We do not have any conscious access to procedural memory, we simply perform what we know.

The PIN memory can be explained with [cued recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recall_%28memory%29#Cued_recall). The image of the post office is associated with the PIN, so whenever you imagine the post office the PIN number is also activated.

Comment: So I believe, remembering movies would also be a kind of episodic memory.